# The state of the INSERTED and DELETED tables in a SQL trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, triggers

I hope someone can help. I have an existing database trigger on a table called Subscriptions. I was going through it to understand where changes were being made. Here is the code:-

```
1:  CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trUpdateSubscription] ON [dbo].[Subscription]
2:  FOR INSERT,UPDATE
3:  AS
4:
5:  IF (UPDATE(IssuesPurchased) OR UPDATE(IssuesSent))
6:  /* If the issues sent = the issues purchased, expire the subscription */
7:
8:  BEGIN
9: 
10: UPDATE Subscription
11: SET StatusID = CASE
12:                WHEN Subscription.IssuesPurchased > Subscription.IssuesSent AND inserted.StatusID<>2 THEN 1 --Activate the subscription.
13:                WHEN Inserted.StatusID = 1 AND Subscription.IssuesPurchased <= Subscription.IssuesSent THEN 3 --Expire the subscription.
14:                ELSE Inserted.StatusID --No Change
15:                END
16:
17:  OUTPUT SYSDATETIME(), INSERTED.*, DELETED.* INTO dbo.Subscription_Change_Log 
18:  FROM Inserted
19:  INNER JOIN Subscription ON Inserted.ID = Subscription.ID
20:  LEFT JOIN Deleted ON Inserted.ID = Deleted.ID
21:  WHERE Deleted.ID IS NULL OR -- when record INSERTED
22:    Inserted.IssuesPurchased <> Deleted.IssuesPurchased OR -- else UPDATE,
23:    Inserted.IssuesSent <> Deleted.IssuesSent              -- so only select records with changed fields
24:
25: END
26: 
27: .........
```

There are some other steps but this segment demonstrates my question.
Before the trigger is executed, the StatusID of the Subscription record is 1. I know that the condition on line 13 is true, so the StatusID is changed to 3. I added an OUTPUT to a log table (on line 17) to check the state of the INSERTED and DELETED table. The log file shows that the StatusID is being upated from 1 to 3. But when I query the INSERTED table directly after line 26, the INSERTED table is still showing StatusID as 1.

So, what I wanted to know is that are there 2 sets of INSERTED and DELETED tables here? Almost like nested transactions?

Sorry for the long winded explanation. Many thanks.

Comment: What type of DML statement are you using to test the trigger?  INSERT or UPDATE?

Comment: I have a stored procedure that inserts a record into the Subscription table. The StatusID is given a default value of 1.

Comment: Depending on the values inserted or updated, the trigger could be recursive.  Are recursive triggers enabled on the db?  An `INSTEAD OF` trigger might be better suited here.

Comment: recursive triggers is set to OFF.